# KendoUI Grid apply filter on dropdown option select

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, datasource, kendo-grid

I have a filterable column that uses a dropdown as a template where the user can select an option to filter by.

How can I make it filter the moment the option is selected rather than the user having to have to click the filter button once the selection is made?

My following code doesn't work. The moment a selection is made the grid refreshes without the filter applied and the dropdown selection is reset.

For my dropdown I have:

```
function salesPersonFilter(element)
{
  element.kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: [{Id: 0, Name: 'Jimbo Jones'}, {Id: 1, Name: 'Jimmy'}],
    dataTextField: 'Name',
    dataValueField: 'Name',
    optionLabel: 'Select salesperson',
    template: '#="<span class=\'filterTrigger\'>"+Name+"</span>" #'
  })
}
```

I have bound a click event to filterTrigger classes:

```
$('.k-list .filterTrigger').click(function()
{
  applyFilters();
})
```

I include the applyFilters() function as reference:

```
function applyFilters() // Custom filters...
{
  var dupes = {};
  var finalFilters = [];

  $.each(filterBus, function(i, el) {
    if(!dupes[el.field])
    {
      dupes[el.field] = true;
      finalFilters.push(el);
    }
  });

  filterBus = finalFilters ;

  grid.dataSource.filter(finalFilters) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it this way, but surely there must be a better way?:

```
function salesPersonFilter(element)
  {
    element.kendoDropDownList({
      dataSource: [{Id: 60, Name: 'Sam'}, {Id: 5, Name: 'Jimmy'}],
      dataTextField: 'Name',
      dataValueField: 'Id',
      optionLabel: 'Select salesperson',
      template: '#="<span class=\'filterTrigger\' data-value=\'"+Id+"\'>"+Name+"</span>" #',
      select: function(e) 
      {// Dirty, is there a better way?
        html = e.item[0].outerHTML;
        html = html.substring(html.indexOf('data-value="')+12);
        traderId = html.substring(0, html.indexOf('"'));

        filterBus.push({
          field: 'traderId',
          operator: 'eq',
          value: traderId
        })
        $('.k-animation-container').hide();
        grid.dataSource.filter(filterBus);
      }
    })
  }
```